# SQL select rating from other table

Tags: php, sql

i have 2 tables

1. table "users" with column user_id
2. table "extra" with column rating and column user_id

how can i select 2 tables and sorting it by rating?

my query

```
SELECT
   USER_ID,
   SUM(RATING) 
FROM
   USERS,
   EXTRA 
WHERE
   EXTRA.USER_ID = '{$row['USER_ID']}'
```

> **Column** '`user_id`' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Try `SELECT users.user_id....`

Comment: Try something like this :
SELECT users.user_id, SUM(rating) FROM users, extra WHERE extra.user_id ='{$row['user_id']}'
Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous -> Its because both tables contains user_id , hence please remember to always specify the user_id you want to use...

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Apart from that, the query is over complicated.  You only need to reference once table:

```
SELECT e.USER_ID, SUM(e.RATING) 
FROM EXTRA e
WHERE e.USER_ID = '{$row['USER_ID']}';
```

Additional notes:

- Provide table aliases for table names, typically the abbreviate of the table name.  This makes queries easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all column names in the query.
- Do not munge query strings with parameter values.  SQL provides parameter placeholders for exactly this purpose.

So the query should look more like:

```
SELECT e.USER_ID, SUM(e.RATING) 
FROM EXTRA e
WHERE e.USER_ID = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your tables have `user_id` column. You must specify which one you want to select:

```
SELECT users.user_id, SUM(rating) FROM users, extra WHERE extra.user_id ='{$row['user_id']}'
```

Comment: can you please help? error is gone, but it shows nothing

Comment: $row = $db->query( "
 
 SELECT dle_users.user_id, dle_users.name, SUM(rating) 
 FROM dle_users 
 JOIN dle_post_extras ON dle_post_extras.user_id = dle_users.user_id  
 WHERE dle_post_extras.user_id ='{$row['user_id']}'

 
 ");
 
 


 while ( $row = $db->get_row() ) {
  

 
 
 echo "    ". $row['name'] ."    <br>"; 
 
 }

Comment: Does `$row['user_id']` has any row in dle_posts_extras?

Comment: hello it works, but it shows only 1 user... how can i create a list with users? while()

Comment: $row = $db->query( "
 
 SELECT dle_users.user_id, dle_users.name, SUM(dle_post_extras.rating) as rating
 FROM dle_users 
 JOIN dle_post_extras ON dle_post_extras.user_id = dle_users.user_id  
 WHERE dle_post_extras.user_id = dle_users.user_id  
 ORDER BY dle_users.user_id
 DESC LIMIT 0,10
 
 ");
 
 


 while ( $row = $db->get_row() ) {
  
 
 
 echo $row['name']; 
 echo $row['rating']; 
 
 }